# adding a link in fluid using action

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

I created an extbase extension for Typo3 that was able to use pdfviewhelpers to create an pdf out of a website.

I achieved this defining actions in the controller and it was quite simple.

Now I'm trying to do this with the Extension "tx_news". I compared everything with my own extension, added the actions to the controller and adapted the templates but i can't get the pdf to be created.

The fluid link looks like this:

```
<f:link.action action="pdf" arguments="{news:newsItem}" class="btn btn-expose" target="_blank">PDF</f:link.action>
```

The Class in NewsController.php like this:

```
**
 * action pdf
 *
 * @param \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News $news
 * @return void
 */
public function pdfAction(\GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News $news = null){
        $demand = $this->createDemandObjectFromSettings($this->settings);
        $demand->setActionAndClass(__METHOD__, __CLASS__);

        $assignedValues = [
            'newsItem' => $news,
            'currentPage' => (int)$currentPage,
            'demand' => $demand,
        ];

        $assignedValues = $this->emitActionSignal('NewsController', self::SIGNAL_NEWS_PDF_ACTION, $assignedValues);
        $this->view->assignMultiple($assignedValues);

        Page::setRegisterProperties($this->settings['pdf']['registerProperties'], $news);
        if (!is_null($news) && is_a($news, 'GeorgRinger\\News\\Domain\\Model\\News')) {
            Cache::addCacheTagsByNewsRecords([$news]);
        }
}
```

Somebody has a hint why this is not functional?

BTW: I know it's not a good idea to mess around in the original code, it's just 4 fun

Comment: Do you get a error ?

Answer (score 2):

For creating a link which points to another extension you must complete the `pluginName`, `extensionName`,`controller` and also if needed the `pageUid` (page where the plugin is).

```
<f:link.action action="pdf" controller="News" pluginName="pi1" extensionName="news" arguments="{news: newsItem}">Generate pdf</f:link.action>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `v2.0.0` the extension `pdfviewhelpers` ships with a built in template for the `news` extension. Simply add the static TypoScript template `pdfviewhelpers - EXT:news` and then link to the PDF view like this:

```html
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}" title="{newsItem.title}" configuration="{additionalParams: '&type=28032013'}">
        Download as PDF
</n:link>
```

It is also possible to customise or completely overwrite the PDF template.